# Reused array in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have a table that I want to reuse only once in the foreach loop for the latter
eg:

```
$tab = [1,2,3]
foreach($tab as $value)
{
    $newTab = $tab;
    dump($newTab);
}
```

Please help me if it is possible!!!

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Help you what? What is the desired result? What is wrong with what you currently have?

Comment: you see for this case $newTab will be used 3 times but I want to use it once

Comment: $newTab is redefined on every iteration, meaning they in fact are only used once. You need to be more clear. Dump only on first iteration ? Define it only on first iteration ? Define and dump once and then exit loop?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on Stack Overflow, J Mar!

If you don't want `$newTab` to be overwritten on subsequent calls, you can do it like this:

```
$tab = [1,2,3]
$newTab = null;

foreach($tab as $value)
{
    if ($newTab === null) {
        $newTab = $value;
        // if you only need this, remove the
        // comment from the following line (break)
        // break;
    }

    // or do more with $value
}

var_dump($newTab); // => 1
```

This will give you the first value in `$tab` that is not `null`. So, with `$tab = [null, null, 1, 2, 3]`, you would still get `1` as a result.

In case you want `$newTab` to be the first item of your array, you can do it with

```
$newTab = $tab[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `break;`

```
$tab = [1,2,3]
foreach($tab as $value)
{
    $newTab = $tab;
    var_dump($newTab);
    break;             //add this to exit the loop after single iteration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move `$newTab` out of the loop and select by the key directly.

```
$tab = [1,2,3];
$newTab = $tab[0]; // Select the first key of the $tab array
var_dump($newTab);

// Output: (int) 1
```

You don't need a loop for this, but if you had other stuff and need the loop to be there for some reason, then just use `break` after the first iteration instead:

```
$tab = [1,2,3]
foreach($tab as $value)
{
    $newTab = $tab;
    var_dump($newTab);
    break;
}

//Output: (int) 1
```

Either of these should work, but the first is more direct and performant, and easier to read later if you need to change it.